# How to set permalinks when posts and pages have different URL structures?

Tags: permalinks

I've been hired to migrate a custom CMS to Wordpress.

The blog page is a subpage of "About Us": `/about-us/blog/`

Each blog post has a URL of `/about-us/blog/xxxx/postname`, where xxxx is the year it was posted.

The site has 10 parent pages, each having `x` sub-pages, so I need webpages to have a URL of `/parent-page/sub-page`

Is it possible to set permalinks that will work for both webpages and blog posts with the above URL structure? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From quick test you *should* be able to just use Custom Structure for it (in Settings / Permalinks):

```
/about-us/blog/%year%/%postname%/
```

I am not *entirely* sure it won't conflict with pages, but it seemed to have worked in my dev install.

Comment: As long as you don't duplicate slugs, i.e. have a Page and an Archive with the same slug, which you shouldn't in this structure, this should work. Pages don't use the same permalink structure as Posts so using this structure will still give you /parent-page/child-page/ structure for Pages.

Comment: That's excellent, appreciated Rarst.